# SQL order table results by 2 date time fields

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I've got a little thing, basically I'm taking the results out of a table, which has the both 'from' (date time) and 'to' (date time) fields, but I only take out the ones that have 'from'=today or 'to'=today, but what I can't do is order them by the date time, without having first the 'from' and after the 'to', I want to mix them, and have all ordered by the time.

an example of the result would be:

```
name          from/to     date time
lorem         from        03/08/2017 10:38
ipsum         to          03/08/2017 11:25
lorem         from        03/08/2017 12:10
```

Query I tried:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM bookings 
 WHERE "'.$date.'"=LEFT(from, 10) 
    OR "'.$date.'"=LEFT(to, 10) 
 ORDER BY date time
```

This results in a list which is ordered by from/to and then date time

Comment: Maybe add your expected result, because I don't fully understand where you want to go with this

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Provide the query that you have written.  (3) What are the results you want?

Comment: just put `ORDER BY date time` at the end of your query?

Comment: SELECT * FROM `bookings` WHERE "'.$date.'"=LEFT(`from`, 10) OR "'.$date.'"=LEFT(`to`, 10)   this is my query, if I put ORDER BY datetime at the end, I get ordererd first the `from` datetimes, and after the `to` datetimes..

Comment: [edit] your question, do not post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I'm using phpMyAdmin 4.0.10.14

Answer (score 0):

as far i understand, you're looking for something like:

first SELECT to get the rows with the from-date - where i added an EVEN rownumber.
second SELECT to get rows with the to-date - where i added an ODD rownumber

finally i just sort them by rownumber. as they have even & odd rownumbers, they will be mixed.

```
SELECT a.name 
      ,a.from_to
      ,a.mydate
  FROM
  (
    SELECT name
          ,'from' AS from_to
          ,date_from as mydate
          ,(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name))  * 2     AS rownum
     WHERE date_from = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())  
    UNION ALL
    SELECT name
          ,'to' AS from_to
          ,date_to as mydate
          ,(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name))  * 2 + 1 AS rownum
     WHERE date_to = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())    
   ) a
ORDER BY a.rownum
```

Comment: this wont "mix" the results though

Comment: @RealCheeseLord oh... i didn't read the "mix". i just updated my answer

Comment: I think you missunderstood again:D  He wants the order to be only dependent on the date. from and to shouldn't matter. but for some reason his querry orders by from and to. at least thats what i think he means

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using SQL Server, combine a UNION operator to merge the FROM and TO datasets, then a common table expression to select the records from that resultset based on your criteria.

```
;with cte as
(
    select name, 'from' [field], [from] [datetime] from foo
    union all
    select name, 'to' [field], [to] from foo
)
select name, field, [datetime] 
from cte 
where convert(date, [datetime]) = '03/08/2017'
order by 3
```

Here's a [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/17df0/1) to demonstrate

Comment: I'm using phpMyAdmin, and I'm trying to do the query through php and get results on frontend, would this work aswell on that?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the question

```
SELECT *, (CASE WHEN "'.$date.'" = LEFT(`from`, 10) THEN `from`
                WHEN "'.$date.'" = LEFT(`to`, 10) THEN `to`
          END) AS ttime
FROM `bookings` WHERE "'.$date.'"=LEFT(`from`, 10) OR "'.$date.'"=LEFT(`to`, 10) ORDER BY ttime
```